# Android FrameLayout position VideoView element by left top width and height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I need to position VideoView element:

Left: 626dip
Top:  86dip
Width:  575dip
Height: 326dip

So when apk start it is in upper right corner...when i press OK button on remote controll it needs VideoView to be in FullScreen (Left: 0, Top: 0, Width: 100%x, Height: 100%y)

How can i make this in xml file?

I im using:

```
  android:layout_gravity="center"
```

So that VideoView Video fill parent and Video is scalled to parent size.

Here is code that i try but it is centered FullScreen and when i press OK button it is centered SmallScreen, and don't know how to set it Left And Top using dp?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <tv.danmaku.ijk.media.widget.VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do only create one state using XML. Switching has to be done in code.
First of all dump the `fill_parent` as it is deprecated. Then if you want to scale it dynamically, let it match the parent or set the smaller size in XML.
Then do the animation transition using view animation. Just as the parent's width and height and scale accordingly using either scale (mind setting the pivot to 0,0) or using size. I would use scaling with computed scale from 626/parentWidth.
But using dips fixes to only one display size/density

Comment: Thanks...can you please post example xml code? So that i can learn and get what i need in apk...i im beginner in android programming so learnigng on example is good start to learn.